# Tuple Equivalence in python

Tags: python

1. What is the definition of tuple equivalence in python?
2. If two tuples have the same element regardless of order, are they equivalent tuples?

I looked in python documentation on tuples equivalence, however, it was not very clear description. 
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: why not try it and see?  `print (1,2) == (2,1)`  :-)

Comment: Obviously, `(True, sum([])) == (0**0, False)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such things are defined in the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in), not in the tutorial.

> Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of
>   corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, each element
>   must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and
>   have the same length.

Comment: What is missing there is that the sequences must be in the same order. `(3,2,1)==(1,2,3)` is False

Comment: @drewk Only because `3 != 1` and `1 != 3`.

Comment: Thank you, you were helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Two tuples are equal if the items in the tuples taken in order are equal.